# Connecting to API Endpoint at www.nba.com timing out from Ubuntu VPS but not locally

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am running the following python script, trying it both locally and from a remote Ubuntu VPS:

```
import requests
import json
import http.client
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import socket

headers= {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
          'Referer': 'https://www.nba.com/'}

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats'


# Your payload data here...


DateFrom = "10/18/2022"
DateTo = "10/18/2022"
Season = '2022-23'


payload = {
    'College': '',
    'Conference': '',
    'Country': '',
    'DateFrom': DateFrom,
    'DateTo' : DateTo,
    'Division' : '',
    'DraftPick' : '',
    'DraftYear' : '',
    'GameScope' : '',
    'GameSegment' : '',
    'Height' : '',
    'ISTRound' : '',
    'LastNGames' : '0',
    'LeagueID': '00',
    'Location' : '',
    'MeasureType' : 'Base',
    'Month' : '0',
    'OpponentTeamID' : '0',
    'Outcome' : '',
    'PORound' : '0',
    'PaceAdjust' : 'N',
    'PerMode' : 'Totals',
    'Period' : '0',
    'PlayerExperience' : '',
    'PlayerPosition' : '',
    'PlusMinus' : 'N',
    'Rank' : 'N',
    'Season': Season,
    'SeasonSegment' : '',
    'SeasonType' : 'Regular Season',
    'ShotClockRange' : '',
    'StarterBench' : '',
    'TeamID' : '0',
    'VsConference' : '',
    'VsDivision' : '',
    'Weight' : ''
}

def get_data_with_requests():
    # Add a debug statement to check if the connection to the endpoint is established.
    print("Connecting to NBA endpoint...")
    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload, timeout=10).json()
    print("Connected to NBA endpoint.")
    return jsonData


# Construct the query string from the payload
query_string = urlencode(payload)

def get_data_with_http_client():
    # Set a custom timeout for the connection (e.g., 10 seconds)
    timeout = 10
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("stats.nba.com", timeout=timeout)
    url_with_query = "/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?" + query_string
    print(url_with_query)    
    try:
        conn.request("GET", url_with_query, headers=headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read().decode("utf-8")
        jsonData = json.loads(data)
        return jsonData
    except socket.timeout as e:
        print(f"Connection timed out: {e}")
        return None

# Try using requests first
try:
    jsonData = get_data_with_requests()
    if jsonData is not None:
        data_size = len(jsonData)
        print(f"Data transfer size: {data_size} bytes")
    else:
        print("Data not received with requests.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error with requests: {e}")
    print("Trying with http.client...")
    try:
        jsonData = get_data_with_http_client()
        if jsonData is not None:
            data_size = len(jsonData)
            print(f"Data transfer size: {data_size} bytes")
        else:
            print("Data not received with http.client.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error with http.client: {e}")
        print("Both methods failed to retrieve data.")
```

The script runs fine locally, using requests, and retrieves the data from the table but when I try to run it remotely in the Ubuntu VPS, I get the following statements and errors:

> Connecting to NBA endpoint... Error with requests:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=443): Read timed out.
> (read timeout=10) Trying with http.client...
> /stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=10%2F18%2F2022&DateTo=10%2F18%2F2022&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&ISTRound=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2022-23&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=
> Connection timed out: The read operation timed out Data not received
> with http.client.

I can ping [www.nba.com](http://www.nba.com) and I don't think anything is blocked or any policy is preventing the possibility of connection. I do this type of scraping, especially using requests, with other sites with no problem.

I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something, thanks in advance.